# codeigniter base_url not working with Firefox only

Tags: php, codeigniter, firefox, base-url

While I am setting my base_url to `http://example.com/`, Ajax works fine in all browsers, except Firefox.

When I set it to `http://www.example.com/`  it works **only** in Firefox, and stops working in other browsers.
It causes the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error (which prevents ajax calls on different domains. It thinks that domains are different because of the `www`)

Has anyone had this problem?
Thanks in advance for your time!

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://example.com/";  // this works in all browsers, not in Firefox
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

$config['base_url'] = "http://www.example.com/";  // this works in only in Firefox, but not in other browsers
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

The Error is "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/index.php/controller/function. Origin http://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

The two links are only different in the 'www'.

Comment: can you please post the code.

Comment: @pckabeer sure, just did

Comment: YOU should make redirection from http://example.com/ to http://www.example.com/ in your domain settings. so that user will always come to http://www.example.com/

Comment: @Waqar Alamgir didnt get that

Comment: In domains management you should redirect user from abc.com to www.abc.com, in this way user will always come to www.abc.com. For instance http:// facebook.com redirects to http:// www.facebook.com

Answer (score 1):

I came across a issue of this kind when I was using custom hosts on windows hosts files.
I added the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

But forgot to add the www.
So to avoid these types of problems I always added on host with and another without `www`.

```
127.0.0.1 example.com www.example.com
```

The issue is that some browsers will add the www automatically on every url, while others don't.

Don't forget to add the hosts on the vhosts configuration file in apache. (assuming you are using apache).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by leaving base_url blank. Now CI just guesses it automatically

```
$config['base_url'] = "";  
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

What actually you are doing is getting your website from Firfox as "www.example.com" and from other browsers "example.com"

Ajax will work fine only when there is no CORS (Cross Origin Request Sharing) violation. It means if you are on www.example.com you cannot launch an ajax request to example.com
Actually **www.example.com** and **example.com** are totally different domains as far browser and search engines are concerned. You can actually host two entirely different websites on each domain.
You should choose between one of these two domain and redirect all requests to other.
To redirect from www to non www

```
if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) === 'www.') {
  header('Location: http'.(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on' ? 's':'').'://' . substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 4).$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit;
}
```

To do the opposite just change === to != in if condition above.

But if, for any reason, you have to keep the two domains, then you should call your ajax script within the current domain.

Then, your base_url() function should return the current domain. for example:

```
function base_url(){
return 'http'.
 (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'s':'').'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}
```